# Can Adwords be cancelled by Google because of improper IE6 site rendering

Tags: google-ads, internet-explorer-6

A client just got a notice from Google saying that their Adwords campaign has been put on hold because the site is:

- Improperly rendering or
- Under construction or
- Needs a special program to run

Now the site is improperly rendering on IE6. On everything else, including IE7+ it's fine. If this is the issue, would putting up a "Looks like you're using an older browser" message instead of the site for IE6 be a solution? Or must the site look good in IE6 for the Adwords campaign to continue?

Comment: View the site using Googlebot as your agent string and see what the site looks like.

Comment: I think it looks fine. All the information is there.

Comment: Its very unlikely to have anything to do with IE6, were there any links in the email, what does the status marker in the adwords dashboard say?

Comment: I agree with @toomanyairmiles that because it's not rendering properly in IE6 Google shouldn't be bothering you about your AdWords campaign. Considering most sites probably don't render well in IE6 who run AdWords it has to be something else on your landing pages.

Comment: @Anagio That was my thought. I'll look into the dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Improperly rendering or

Ensure **no cloaking** is in place;

> Under construction or

All **links are OK**;

> Needs a special program to run

http://damionbrown.com/2011/01/google-apparently-penalising-adwords-advertisers-with-flash-landing-pages/